# Cut a file into multiple files (Java)

Tags: java

I use Java Camel to my project (Talend).
I need your help for a method to solve this problem. I have this file:

```
D0000000000000000000
EEASTDE                                                                                                                                                                             
ELASPDF  
ELASQML
EEASTDE                                                                                                                                                                                    
ELASPDF
ELASQHG
F00000006
```

How I can cut in java this way (in 2 file) ?

```
EEASTDE                                                                                                                                                                                    
ELASPDF
ELASQML
```

And:

```
EEASTDE                                                                                                                                                                                   
ELASPDF
ELASQHG
```

I have to cut the file according to the head EEASTDE. It's an example, I could have several times the header EEASTDE (3, 4, 5...).
I thought of the HashMap, the arraylist but I don't know how to make the code because I'm not indicate the line EEASTDE as a unique key and the

Here is my test code but it doesn't work:

```
public class bean_test implements Processor{


private static final String MDS_ENDPOINT_NAME = "MDSEndpoint";
private static final String EEASTD_HEADER = "EEASTDE";
private static final int EEASTD_HEADER_START_POSITION = 0;
private static final int EEASTD_HEADER_END_POSITION = 7;
private static final String START_OF_FILE_TAG = "D";
private static final String END_OF_FILE_TAG = "F";

@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

    ProducerTemplate producerTemplate = exchange.getContext().createProducerTemplate();
    String MDSEndpoint = exchange.getIn().getHeader(MDS_ENDPOINT_NAME, String.class);
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class).getBytes());
    extractFromMDS(producerTemplate, is, MDSEndpoint, new HashMap<String, Object>(exchange.getIn().getHeaders()));

}

private void extractFromMDS(ProducerTemplate producerTemplate, InputStream content, String MDSEndpoint, Map<String, Object> headers){
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
    String line;
    try {
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            if(!line.startsWith(START_OF_FILE_TAG) && !line.startsWith(END_OF_FILE_TAG)){
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = null;
                if(line.substring(EEASTD_HEADER_START_POSITION, EEASTD_HEADER_END_POSITION).equals(EEASTD_HEADER)){
                    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    stringBuilder.append("\n"+(line));

                }
            producerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeaders(MDSEndpoint, stringBuilder.toString(), headers);
        }
    }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        try {
            if(br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Have you an idea ?

Thank you in advance.

Natacha.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: As note on Camel: you should probably use [file](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html) endpoints to read input files instead of manually opening inputstreams.